# No sound in Flash player but HTML5 player is fine

Tags: sound, video, flash, youtube

Sound on my Notebook is working fine, but when I visit Youtube and play a video using flash, the video runs fine but without sound. If I play same video with HTML5 player, sound is back.

Any ideas?

Linux version:

```
rafael@rafa-note:~$ uname --all
Linux rafa-note 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My version of Ubuntu:

```
rafael@rafa-note:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

My modules:

```
rafael@rafa-note:~$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36913  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    78399  1 
cdc_acm                26898  0 
uvcvideo               80847  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40513  1 uvcvideo
videodev              129260  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
parport_pc             28152  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
coretemp               13355  0 
kvm_intel             132891  0 
kvm                   443165  1 
kvm_intel 
bnep                   18036  2 
rfcomm                 42641  0 
bluetooth             228619  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_intel          39619  3 
snd_hda_codec         136453  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97451  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30180  1 snd_seq_midi
microcode              22881  0 
snd_seq                61554  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
psmouse                95870  0 
intel_ips              17978  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
i915                  600351  3 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
drm_kms_helper         49394  1 i915
drm                   286313  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd                    68876  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
ndiswrapper           283323  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei                    41158  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
topstar_laptop         12837  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 topstar_laptop
binfmt_misc            17500  1 
video                  19390  1 i915
mac_hid                13205  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12540  0 
usbhid                 47074  0 
hid                   101002  2 hid_generic,usbhid
usb_storage            57204  0 
r8169                  67446  0 
ahci                   25731  3 
libahci                31364  1 ahci
```

SOLUTION:

sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
rafael@rafa-note:~$ sudo gstreamer-properties

in plugin: SET PulseAudio

Comment: English is not that bad ...even i can understand what you are trying to say....

Comment: HDMI Audio? if so `echo -e "pcm.pulse {\ntype pulse\n}\nctl.pulse {\ntype pulse\n}\npcm.\!default {\ntype pulse\n}\nctl.\!default {\ntype pulse\n}" | sudo tee -a /etc/asound.conf` then logout and in and try it

Comment: now my sound (include players and OS sounds) is gone :(

Answer (score 1):

can you reinstall your flash?

First, click on the Ubuntu Software Center icon. This icon located on the launcher bar at the left hand side of the screen.

Second, Type in "flashplugin-installer" on the search bar and press enter.

Third, You should find the Adobe Flash plugin pop up in the search results.

Fourth, click on the button to remove and click on it again to install.

Use Mozilla, see if it works...

Comment: yes.. i reinstall many times :(